# Uncheck all JQuery radio buttonset at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Using jQ-ui's buttonset feature

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#radio" ).buttonset();
    });
    </script>


    <div id="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
    </div>
```

Is there any way to uncheck all radio buttons of buttonset at once?

Comment: should `$( "#radio" )` be instead `$( "radio" )`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can uncheck them them with the following (updated for jQuery UI 1.9:

```
$('#radio input').removeAttr('checked');
// Refresh the jQuery UI buttonset.                  
$( "#radio" ).buttonset('refresh');
​
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/Lmnnp/19/).

Comment: Nice. Answer keeps getting shorter. :)

Comment: That fiddle doesn't seem to be successfully turning the radio buttons into a jQuery UI button set, which is why it seems to work. It doesn't, quite, Frédéric is right that you have to do the refresh.

Comment: This doesn't work in jQuery 1.9 and doesn't affect jQuery UI buttonsets. the answer below is the better answer.

Comment: @CoryDorning I've updated the answer & the fiddle, thanks for the heads up

Comment: This answer is wrong as .removeAttr('checked'); wont uncheck the radio. See jQuery API.

Answer (score 15):

You can match all the radio buttons and use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to uncheck them.

However, you also have to refresh the buttonset widget after doing so:

```
$("#radio").find("input:radio").prop("checked", false).end()
           .buttonset("refresh");
```

Answer (score 14):

**Before jQuery 1.6 version**

```
$(':radio').attr('checked', false);
```

OR

```
$(':radio').removeAttr('checked');
```

**After jQuery 1.6+**

```
$(':radio').prop('checked', false);
```

OR

```
$(':radio').removeProp('checked');
```

Answer (score 1):

Discovered this by accident...with jQuery 1.9.1 using a class name for the buttonset left all the buttons initially unset.  Not yet sure if there are ramifications to this, but handy to know.

```
$( "div.myclass" ).buttonset();

<div id="myDiv" class="myclass">
    <input type="radio" name="myname" id="id1" value="1"><label for="id1">Label1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="myname" id="id2" value="2"><label for="id2">Label2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="myname" id="id3" value="3"><label for="id3">Label2</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That works for me

```
$('input:radio[name="RadioName"]').each(function () { $(this).attr('checked', false); });
```

Answer (score 0):

For JQuery 1.12+

Wrap the radio buttons within a `<div>` and give it an id (e.g. "radio")

`$("#radio").find("input:radio").prop("checked", false)`

Answer (score 0):

> Javascirpt native way to achieve this

```js
function reset(){
//var list = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
var list =document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked')
debugger
list.forEach(element => { 
if(element.checked){element.checked=false}}
    
);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" class="myclass">
    <input type="radio" name="myname" id="id1"  value="1"><label for="id1">Label1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="myname" id="id2" value="2"><label for="id2">Label2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="myname" id="id3" checked value="3"><label for="id3">Label3</label>
</div>

<button onclick="reset()">reset me</button>
```